# Need to store difference in dates into an int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to put the difference in minutes, between two dates into an int in SQL server 2005. I get the error -

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

SQL -

```
DECLARE @id varchar(10)
DECLARE @diff int

SET @id = 'D5234'
SET @diff = SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, [PROC].[START_DATE], [PROC].[END_DATE]) 
FROM [PROCESSES] AS [PROC]
WHERE [PROC].[ID] = @id
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: How did you get "Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'" with the code you showed? I don't see SELECT there at all

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to use:

```
SELECT @diff = DATEDIFF(minute, [PROC].[START_DATE], [PROC].[END_DATE]) 
FROM [PROCESSES] AS [PROC]
WHERE [PROC].[ID] = @id;
```

Or

```
SET @diff = (SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, [PROC].[START_DATE], [PROC].[END_DATE]) 
            FROM [PROCESSES] AS [PROC]
            WHERE [PROC].[ID] = @id);
```

(With your select statement in parentheses).

If you have multiple rows matching, the former will only set @diff to be the last row encountered, the latter will fail if you have multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why I cannot specify FROM when using SET ?

Comment: the former will only set @diff to be the last row encountered - not a problem when ID is unique for each row.

Comment: As to why you can't use `FROM` with `SET`, I don't know. I suspect there is a good reason though.